# Making Vuetify work properly in IE11

Tags: vuetify.js, webpacker, babel-polyfill

Our app (https://web.hashlearn.com) is built with Vuetify works and looks awesome in all browsers except IE11 (we don't support < IE11). This is essentially a Rails app with Webpacker, VueJS, and Vuetify (0.16.9). Most of the things seem to work except a few issues in IE11, the icons just don't show up in IE. I've tried multiple things including:

1. Installing and including babel-polyfill via npm and importing it into our application.js
2. Including babel-polyfill via Webpacker entry config as suggested here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/523#issuecomment-309871748

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "> 1%",
        "node": "current",
        "uglify": true
      },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }]
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }],
    ["transform-runtime", { "polyfill": false, "regenerator": true }]
  ]
}
```

Has anybody faced this kind of issues? how did you solve the issues? Most of the issues reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20ie11) don't seem to have proper solutions though.

Comment: Syed Aslam, did you get any update on this problem please?

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3020 has a fixed icon related IE11 compatibility issue

Comment: Excellent, thanks @SimonD.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/nuxt/issues/80